# Oauth authentication with laravel passport for mobile app

Tags: oauth, authorization, microservices, access-token, laravel-passport

I am using laravel passport for authorization from mobile app.

But I'm not sure where to place the `client credentials` i.e `client_id/client_secret` and `redirect_uri`.

1. Will it be placed at mobile app end and they will pass these to an API while authenticating to get tokens or these details be kept at server side in some env variables for security purpose?
2. And will the every user be having different client_id and secret or it will be same for all users throughout the application.

Answer (score 0):

The client credentials grant type is for when you want your application to contact the server with out a user. For example a weather app will contact the server to get the latest weather data. It does not need to user to login to do this. You want to client credentials because you do not want  everyone using your api. It is a way to protect your api and only allow your approved apps to access the api information.

1. Yes you will pass the client_id/client_secret from your mobile/desktop application to the /oauth/token url on your server so it will return an access token for you to use when getting all the information through the api.
2. The client_id and client secret do not need a user. It is for the client (Mobile/Desktop application). But it will be the same for every user since they all will be using the same mobile/Desktop application.